# Run SyncToy silently

Tags: scheduled-tasks, synctoy

How can I schedule SyncToy to run every day, but also to run silently, i.e. with no GUI and without interrupting other applications?

Currently I have it set to run every day, but it pops up a command window which comes to the front and steals focus from XBMC if it is open.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your Task Scheduler job like this:

> Actions tab -> Action: [Start a Program] -> Edit

*Then Enter* `Program/script`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

*And then Enter* `Add Arguments`:

```
/c start "Scheduled Task - SyncToy" /MIN "C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R
```

When this task runs, a command window opens very briefly and closes, starting a new minimised window running SyncToy 2.1.